# Adding a label to an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-visualization, datatemplate, timeline

Visual presentation is not my strong side when it comes to programming. I'm developing a small program for my company, ment to aid in a schedule overview (can also be described as a timeline).

The background works work as expected, so I don't include this code here as it's not a question of why it's not displaying this data or so. My questions are more on how to present it visually better.

The timeline shows up as a gray bar and is then populated with buttons on the timeline where an event is taking place.

I would like your advice on how I can:

1. Add a label to the left of the gray bar.
2. Add a visual timeline (i.e. timestamps) as a gradient above the gray bar, so it visually presents where in the timeline is 3 o'clock and where is 6 o'clock.

or, i would appriciate some advice on where I can read more about it, a hint in the right direction.

Thank you!

```
<Window x:Class="Test.BookingOverview"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Bokningsöversikt" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:EventLengthConverter x:Key="mEventLengthConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TimeLines}" Margin="10,90,10,27" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <ItemsControl x:Name="TimeLine" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Events}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <Grid x:Name="EventContainer" Height="20" Margin="5" Background="Gainsboro">

                                        </Grid>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Background="Yellow" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <Button.Margin>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mEventLengthConverter}">
                                                    <Binding ElementName="TimeLine" Path="DataContext.Duration"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Start"/>
                                                    <Binding ElementName="EventContainer" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </Button.Margin>
                                            <Button.Width>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mEventLengthConverter}">
                                                    <Binding ElementName="TimeLine" Path="DataContext.Duration"/>
                                                    <Binding Path="Duration"/>
                                                    <Binding ElementName="EventContainer" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </Button.Width>
                                            <Button.Content>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding customer}"></TextBlock>
                                            </Button.Content>
                                            <Button.ContextMenu>
                                                <ContextMenu Name="Test">
                                                    <MenuItem Header="Testar contextmenu"></MenuItem>
                                                    <Separator></Separator>
                                                    <MenuItem Header="Testar igen"></MenuItem>
                                                </ContextMenu>
                                            </Button.ContextMenu>
                                            <Button.ToolTip>
                                                <ToolTip Content="Testar"></ToolTip>
                                            </Button.ToolTip>

                                        </Button>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

Aepot got me in the right direction, but currently it's creating rows of labeling and then the acctual timelines. Most likely due to something I din't understand by using ItemsControls.

Changes made to the code according to the suggestion of Aepot:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="90,123,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Bokningsöversikt"></TextBlock>
            
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TimeLines}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="TimeLine" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Events}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Grid x:Name="EventContainer" Grid.Column="2" Height="20" Margin="5" Background="Gainsboro"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <Binding ElementName="EventContainer" Path="DataContext.RegNr"/>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TimeLines}" >
                <ItemsControl.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding RegNr}"/>
                        <Separator></Separator>
                        <MenuItem Header="Test"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ItemsControl.ContextMenu>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="TimeLine" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Events}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Grid x:Name="EventContainer" Grid.Column="2" Height="20" Margin="5" Background="Gainsboro"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Background="Yellow" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                        <Button.Margin>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mEventLengthConverter}">
                                                <Binding ElementName="TimeLine" Path="DataContext.Duration"/>
                                                <Binding Path="Start"/>
                                                <Binding ElementName="EventContainer" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Button.Margin>
                                        <Button.Width>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mEventLengthConverter}">
                                                <Binding ElementName="TimeLine" Path="DataContext.Duration"/>
                                                <Binding Path="Duration"/>
                                                <Binding ElementName="EventContainer" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Button.Width>
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding customer}"></TextBlock>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                        <Button.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu Name="Test">
                                                <MenuItem Header="Testar contextmenu"></MenuItem>
                                                <Separator></Separator>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Testar igen"></MenuItem>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </Button.ContextMenu>
                                        <Button.ToolTip>
                                            <ToolTip Content="Testar"></ToolTip>
                                        </Button.ToolTip>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: By gradient you literally mean a colour or tonal gradient? You could use a rectangle with a lineargradientbrush as fill. Put multiple gradientstops in it. You can have hard edges transitions if you put two gradientstops together and or gradients between each stop.

Comment: @Andy sorry, I should probably have used another word to describe the what I wanted to achive, I'm looking for something that would be more of a scale/grade. The code behind uses a timespan to determain where events should be situated on the "row". But it lacks a scale to indicate what time is this. I.e. If the timespan is set to 24 hours, the middle of the "row" should therefor indicate 12 hours, at that point (and for all other hours) I would like to make a mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** use `TextBlock` instead of `Label` in case of displaying text because it's better optimized for that.

Try wrapping the controls with `StackPanel`.

```xaml
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="My timeline"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ItemsControl .../><!-- with TextBlocks for labeling timeline -->
        <ItemsControl .../><!-- existing one -->
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

You can also use `StackPanel` as Control to use in `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

Or this way, more friendly if you're familiar with HTML `<table>`

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="My timeline"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" .../><!-- with TextBlocks for labeling timeline -->
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" .../><!-- existing one -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion, I tried it out your way and it was far better than anything I tried during the day, grids and so on. Currently the labeling is not to the left of the acctual timelines, it is first generated and then the timelines are genereated, insted of them being on the same row. I update the code with what I have understood from you suggestion. I would greatly appriciate if you would have the time to yet again hint me in the right direction of what I have not understood.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there, but it's the labeling that doesn't work. The textblock "My timeline" is not repeating itself, even with the code before. I don't know but maybe I'm repeating myself in the code from the ItemsControl "Labeling timeline" All the labels are printed and all the timelines are printed, like:
Label
Label
Label
Timeline
Timeline
Timeline

when it should be
Label Timeline
Label Timeline
Label Timeline

Maybe they should all be included in the "exisiting one"?

Comment: @Calleman I can't tell more, I don't understand the objective. I just showed a way to markup a group of controls. All repeatable controls must be inside of Items Control. I'm sorry.

Comment: That's alright and no need to apologize, I'm most grateful that you have hinted me in the right direction and showed me something I didn't knew. You code led me to do a quickfix of letting them run as they were, but in two grids to control the layout, probably not the best, but for now it does the trick :)

Comment: @Calleman ok, but don't kill yourself with margins, use `Grid` rows and columns. I've updated the answer with one more way to do it. The layout can be totally adaptive when you're resizing the `Window` without any specific layout behavior handlers. And WPF have a lot of tools to make it easy.

Comment: @Calleman note that `Grid.Row="0"` and `Grid.Column="0"` are default values and you may not include it into the XAML. `Grid` row/column Definition without size means `Width="*"` and `Height="*"` accordingly, these are defaults too. Thus you may split the UI and use relative `Margin` for each `Control` instead of absolute. `Margin="90,123,0,0"` looks weird at all. :)

Comment: @Calleman One more syntax tip `Margin="5,5,5,5"` can be shorten as `Margin="5"`, `Margin="10,5,10,5"` can be `Margin="10,5"` with the same result. You can create a blank WPF project and play with all above suggestions there.